# swfobject // error in Chrome & IE, works in FF // OR // Fixed in IE & Chrome and not FF

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, swfobject

Using  SWFObject 2.2, making code with swfobject_generator_1_2_air  for dynamic files swaps, I can get my .swf to swap with static image, as I want in all browsers.

Unfortunately, the css navigation menu hides behind the .swf in Chrome 22 & IE9 64x when I'm using those in testing.  However, Opera & FF 16.0.1 on Win7 64x  I the menu does not hide behind .swf

I thought I had a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081863/how-to-prevent-javascript-menu-from-getting-hidden-under-flash-video-swfobject).   Yet while adding

```
params.wmode = "opaque";
```

fixed the navigation menu error in both Chrome & IE, FF failed. Opera succeeded in either manifestation (with or without above code added).  I couldn't test safari at this time.

Thanks.

---

### Nav partially hidden behind .swf in Chrome / IE9 while both .swf / nav work FF / opera

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};

        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "ULA AirX Backpack 360 photos";
        swfobject.embedSWF("360/airx/airx.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "400", "575", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

---

### Nav is visible: Chrome & IE & Opera, but  FF does not display .swf

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        params.wmode = "opaque";
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = "ULA AirX Backpack 360 photos";
        swfobject.embedSWF("360/airx/airx.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "400", "575", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell without an actual HTML code to test.

Comment: @Jay thanks... I can provide more. Do you recommend a bin site or a direct link to pages?

Answer (score 0):

First, set the SWF to use `wmode` `opaque` or `transparent`. It's recommended that you stick to `opaque` unless you truly need the SWF to be transparent. `transparent` uses much more CPU and introduces quirks; `opaque` is considered safer.

Second, ensure that you have specified `position` in your CSS.  It can be `absolute` or `relative`, but you need to specify it. (And no, `z-index` has no impact, as the Flash Player plugin ignores `z-index`.)

See this [tutorial](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/placing-html-elements-over-a-flash-movie/) for a working example.